# Using executorservice to control runtime process

Tags: java, file-io, executorservice

I use a Runnable object to run a processCommand and do some processing that take some amount of time (let's call it insideprocess). In the end of the insideprocess, it will write something to a text file. The idea is, if for some specified time the insideprocess is still not finish, it has to be killed, so I use ExecutorService to handle it. But if the insideprocess finishes earlier than the specified time, it will interrupt the ExecutorService so the main thread can continue to the next task.

But the problem is, sometimes, the insideprocess doesn't create a file at all or it create a file but there's nothing written in it. It happens when the insideprocess finishes earlier than the specified time. I don't know what is wrong with my implementation. Note that, if I do the process manually (without using ExecutorService) the process runs well and it writes everything correctly.

Here I post my code to do the work:

```
public void process(){


    for (int i = 0; i < stoppingTime.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 2 * i; j < 2 * (i + 1); j++) {
            final int temp = j;
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Process p = null;

                    int ex = 1;

                    try {
                        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                                processCommand.get(temp));

                        while (ex != 0) {
                            try {
                                //sleep every 30 second then check the exitValue
                                Thread.sleep(30000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            }
                            ex = p.exitValue();
                            p.destroy();                                
                        }                           
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("IOException");
                    }
                }

            };

            Future future = executor.submit(r);

            try {
                System.out.println("Started..");
                future.get(stoppingTime[i], TimeUnit.SECONDS);                  
                System.out.println("Finished!");
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                System.out.println("Terminated!");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Future gets InterruptedException");
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                System.out.println("Future gets ExecutionException");
            }
            executor.shutdownNow();
            System.out.println("shutdown executor");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should ALWAYS consume standard out and err streams of a native process. Have a look here http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: @Svilen That is a great article.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, thought I'd try it anyway.

Firstly, you're getting an `ExecutorService` inside the double loop, in the same block as the defined `Runnable`.  If you would like to get the returned value of natively executing `"processCommand"` and then continue to the next task like you say, then you need to reuse that `ExecutorService` by instantiating it before the loops.

Secondly, `stoppingTime[i]` is `int` whereas `Future.get(...)` takes `long`.